# Node installs loads of modules

Tags: node.js, npm, laravel-elixir

I am trying to install some node modules for my application. 
Now after entering this command: `npm install laravel-elixir` it creates a folder `node_modules`and installes over a hundred modules!! this cannot be right.

How would I solve this problem?

Comment: It has [39 dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir), and those dependencies have dependencies of their own, so hundreds of modules is not unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I solve this problem?

Write your own code from scratch.

Really, there's very little that can be done. Large dependency trees are *very* common in Node.js. A lot of modules are built on the backs of other modules. The module in question is an especially large piece of software, trying to do what seems like a lot of different things, and relying on many other modules to do so.

You can try

```
$ npm install laravel-elixir --no-optional
```

to see if you can trim some optional dependencies from the tree. Another methood is to add `optional=false` to your `.npmrc`.

In my brief, and unscientific testing this seems to drop about six dependencies from the tree. Not much.

You should also make sure you've updated to `npm 3.0` (`3.8.6` being the latest), as it does a better job of [flattening dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3).

Sometimes there are needless dependencies in the middle of a tree, and in that event there is not much you can do other than reach out to the maintainers, and see if these dependencies can be removed, but then all the downstream packages will need to update.

This is generally called *depedency hell*, and it is an unfortunate symptom of certain modules that rely on too many submodules.

In reality though, if this module does what you need it to do, and there are no ill effects of having many dependencies installed, does it *really* matter? Other than the install time, when using the module, can you tell that it is pulling in a lot of other modules?